# How to determine the X11 loaded font name?

Tags: fonts, x11

If I load a font using:

```
char *fName = (char *)"*-c-60-iso8859-1";
XFontStruct *font = XLoadQueryFont(disp, fName);
```

it could be any of several fonts matching the wildcarded name.
How can I determine the full name of the one actually loaded?

[EDIT] Corrected wildcard name to match several: `-c-` was `-m-` which didn't match any. [END]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the `XA_FONT` property of the font.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if (!d)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Oops, can't open display\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (*++argv)
    {
        XFontStruct* f = XLoadQueryFont(d, *argv);
        unsigned long ret;
        if (f == 0)
            printf ("XLoadQueryFont failed for %s!\n", *argv);
        else
        {
            if (!XGetFontProperty(f, XA_FONT, &ret))
                printf ("XGetFontProperty(%s, XA_FONT) failed!\n", *argv);
            else
                printf ("Full name for %s is %s\n", *argv, XGetAtomName(d, (Atom)ret));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
$ ./prog r14 9x15bold foo
Full name for r14 is -Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--14-130-75-75-C-70-JISX0201.1976-0
Full name for 9x15bold is -Misc-Fixed-Bold-R-Normal--15-140-75-75-C-90-ISO8859-1
XLoadQueryFont failed for foo!
```

Comment: Very good. Thanks. I am experimenting also with Xft fonts now.

Comment: Xft is the way, serverside fonts are dead. I don't even have any installed, except mandatory fixed fonts.

Comment: Finally got to using this, and it works. XLoadQueryFont() does a very poor job of approximating anything like what I want. Some I would not actually consider poor, but the result of bugs.

Comment: What *do* you want? Note `XLoadQueryFont` is a rather old and well-established API, any bugs you perceive are likely to be results of misunderstanding rather than actual bugs.

Comment: Yes, I suspect you are quite right. Want?... Well just for my learning to go faster ;) I want to get to the real purpose of my work. BTW, thank you again for helping it go faster.